# Gzip files and Angular 2

Tags: angular, gzip

I have some file zipped using gzip (.gz file type) stores on my server.

I use a service (Angular 2) and an observable to download the file to the client machine:

```
this.rest.getFile(this.stlLocation).subscribe(
            data => {

                    console.log(data);
                    //OK, now I have my .gz file containing a compressed JSON file. 
                    //What do I need to do in angular 2 to decompress and read the JSON data in the file?

                },
                err => {
                    this.msgs.push({severity: 'error', summary: 'Error Message', detail: err});
                }
            );
```

How can I unzip and get the plain JSON file once successfully downloaded?

**updates...**

Thank you to joh for sending me on the right path. See accepted answer. After a bit of reading, I have implemented the following solution.

According to Joh:

> "If you are downloading the file to a browser, you shouldn't have to
>   do anything. Browsers add the Accept-Encoding: 'deflate' header
>   automatically; it is both unnecessary and not good practice to do this
>   at a DOM/JS level."

If you are using NGINX the following link may help you out:

[NGINX COMPRESSION AND DECOMPRESSION](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/compression-and-decompression/)

A massive thank you to all the other people that tried to help with different solutions. I really appreciate the time you took try answering my question.

Comment: Use any gzip extractor

Comment: Hi Rahul, is it a javascript library? Where can I find it, please?

Comment: Dino it will be downloaded in your local system how will you access that? I was talkig about the end user

Comment: Ciao Rahul, thank you very much for your help. I followed another root but I appreciate your effort. Dino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are downloading the file to a browser, you shouldn't have to do anything. Browsers themselves add the `Accept-Encoding: 'deflate'` header automatically; it is both unnecessary and not good practice to do this at a DOM/JS level because the browser should take care of this for you. GZipping was meant for network transfer, and encoding is handled in request headers; the browser should unwrap this for you.

So, once you have the file, it should be usable as JSON (if using Angular's `Http` service, you will have to parse the JSON i.e. `Observable.map(res => res.json())` ).

Side note: if this uncompressed file is under ~1.4Kb, it's probably better off left un-gzipped. Files that small are going to be sent in a single packet anyway, and gzipping will just add a small overhead to the DOM and CPU.

Comment: Hi joh, forgive my ignorance but I am developing only a small part of the app. What is happening is the following: someone created the files I need to download (large JSON), gzip then and upload them to the server. My job is to download them, unzip them and render the object stored into the file. The line Observable.map(res => res.json()) in my service does not return a file but if I inspect the result of res => res, I can see the unzipped file. I believe I do not understand at what level the Gzip compression works and how to apply it correctly.

Comment: Hi Joh, after a bit of reading I think I have understood what you meant and I have implemented the solution described in the "updated section" of my question. Thank you very much for your invaluable help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using npm you could use something like this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gzipy

from usage:

```
 //Import gzipy  
var gzipy = require('gzipy');

//Compress a file  
gzipy.compress('./file.txt', './file.txt.gz', function(error)
{
  //Handle the error  
  if(error){ /* Something went wrong... */ } 

  console.log('File compressed!');
});

//Decompress a file 
gzipy.decompress('./document.pdf.gz', './document.pdf', function(error)
{
  //Handle the error  
  if(error){ /* Something went wrong... */ } 

  console.log('File decompressed');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Erica. In the end, I have followed another path but I appreciate the time you dedicate trying to help me. Thank you for sharing the knowledge, I am sure gzipy will prove useful in the future. Dino

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you found something that worked for you :)